# Cómo visualizar un archivo .pdf en una página

Tags: php, javascript, jspdf

Necesito mostrar un documento .pdf en una página. Estoy utilizando PDF.js, la libreria de Mozilla.

Los archivos pdf están en un servidor ftp, pues no quiero descargarlos por razones de espacio en el servidor.

Intenté esto y no funciona:

```
<div id="preview" class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <iframe id="FramePDF" src="ftp://Usuario:Clave@Server/CarpetaPDF/Prueba.pdf" width="700" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya resolvi, simplemente utilize la funcion `file_get_contents` de php y el string que me devuelve lo converti en un base64 , luego hice lo que indica esta pagina https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/helloworld64.html y funciono perfectamente, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el siguiente codigo

```
<object data="ftp://Usuario:Clave@Server/CarpetaPDF/Prueba.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="ftp://Usuario:Clave@Server/CarpetaPDF/Prueba.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

espero te sirva

Comment: lo acabo de probar y no funciono, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.! @Jesus Martiz

Comment: tienes un error con el dns donde esta alojado el documento ftp://server/CarpetaPDF/Prueba.pdf verificalo por ti mismo

Comment: no creo que ese sea el caso, ya que el mismo ftp lo utilizo para guardar imágenes y funciona cuando las obtengo