# ¿Por que mi app hecha en laravel 5.4 no genera el pdf con barryvdh/laravel-dompdf 8.0?

Tags: php, laravel-5, pdf

Justo tengo [**este mismo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777252/download-in-browser-with-ajax-request) problema.

Instalo el paquete correctamente y todo bien hasta allí, pero intento generar el pdf con **[barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)**, pero todos mis intentos han sido fallidos.

**Mi ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'equipos/generarPdf',
        global: false,
    data: {
        'data': data
    },
}).then(
    function(data) {
        console.log("Documento Generado");
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
    }, function() {
        console.log('this will run if the deferred generates a progress update');
    }
);
```

*Nota:* en la ejecución del ajax me retorna q no hubo ningún problema.

**Mi ruta:**

```
Route::post('equipos/generarPdf','EquiposController@generarPdf');
```

*Nota:* En cuanto a la ruta me la reconoce bien.

**Mi controlador (funcion generarPdf):**

```
public function generarPdf(Request $req) {
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('Test');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

*Nota:* cuando llega acá no hace nada mi app y reviso en `network` de Google Chrome y me devuelve lo siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 1:**

Probé de distintas maneras:

Acá cargo el archivo y ejecuto **stream**:

```
public function generarPdf(Request $req) {
    $datos = $req->data;
    $name_file = $datos[1].'-'.$datos[2].'.pdf';
    $file_storage = storage_path('app\public\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;
    $file_public = public_path('storage\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('equipos.pdf_vista', $datos);
    $pdf->setPaper('a4');
    $pdf->setWarnings(false);
    $pdf->save($file_storage);
    return $pdf->loadFile($file_public)->stream($name_file);
}
```

Acá ejecuto **stream**:

```
public function generarPdf(Request $req) {
    $datos = $req->data;
    $name_file = $datos[1].'-'.$datos[2].'.pdf';
    $file_storage = storage_path('app\public\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;
    $file_public = public_path('storage\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('equipos.pdf_vista', $datos);
    $pdf->setPaper('a4');
    $pdf->setWarnings(false);
    $pdf->save($file_storage);
    return $pdf->stream($name_file);
}
```

Acá descargo el archivo:

```
public function generarPdf(Request $req) {
    $datos = $req->data;
    $name_file = $datos[1].'-'.$datos[2].'.pdf';
    $file_storage = storage_path('app\public\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;
    $file_public = public_path('storage\pdf\equipos\\').$name_file;

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('equipos.pdf_vista', $datos);
    $pdf->setPaper('a4');
    $pdf->setWarnings(false);
    $pdf->save($file_storage);
    return $pdf->download($name_file);
}
```

***NOTA:*** el archivo es creado en la carpeta `publica` de laravel pero no genera la descarga del archivo, para las 3 opciones no obtengo un error, sino que en **response** obtengo lo mismo que la imagen anteriormente expuesta.

Comment: ¿Sera que lo que obtengo por `response` requiere de alguna interpretación o conversión?

Comment: ¿Sera que esta [**respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76928/c%C3%B3mo-visualizar-un-archivo-pdf-en-una-p%C3%A1gina/77267#77267) tiene algo que ver con mi problema?

Comment: ¿cómo va el avance en solucionar este problema? Lo digo porque vi una larga conversación incluyendo hasta Teamviewer (!!!!??), por lo cual quiero saber si puede ser conveniente invertir algo de tiempo, para tampoco perderlo si están muy cerca de solucionarlo.

Comment: @Shaz lo solucionamos con `XMLHttpRequest();` hay alguna manera de hacerlo con el ajax normal? por ese metodo no puedo pasar datos por `Request`. Ademas el `buffer` me inhabilita el `debugbar`.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con el AJAX normal? Hasta donde yo sé la técnica "original" de AJAX es la de XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya te regresa en el console log los simbolos del PDF, lo unico que tienes mal es tu ajax. Usa esto:

```
$.ajax({                 
         type: 'post',
         url: 'equipos/generarPdf',
         global: false,
         data: {
           'data': data
         }
         //,dataType: "text",
         //,async: false
        }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(ruta);
                var nombreLogico = "XXX";
                var parametros = "dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=1050";
                var htmlText = "<embed width=100% height=100% type='application/pdf' src='data:application/pdf," + escape(data) + "'></embed>";
                var detailWindow = window.open("", nombreLogico, parametros);
                detailWindow.document.write(htmlText);
                detailWindow.document.close();
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error\njqXHR=" + jqXHR + "\nstatus=" + textStatus + "\nerror=" + errorThrown);
        }).always(function(dataORjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_ORerrorThrown) {
            //alert( "complete" );
        });
```

Si aun asi no funciona, revisa en ese console.log que en los simbolos del PDF no aparezcan caracteres extraños. Si aparecen, tienes que probar combinaciones de utf8 encode y utf8 decode del lado de javascript y de php hasta que funcione.

Comment: Lo que obtengo por console.log es algo como lo siguiente: `%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (dompdf <0f418c6b> + CPDF)
/CreationDate (D:20170626164219+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20170626164219+00'00')
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000]`

Comment: Con tu código [***obtuve esto***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmVGX.png)

Comment: eso es correcto, te falta mostrarlo con el codigo adentro del done

Comment: no entendí :/ hermano

Comment: Cuando ya puedes pintar el binario del pdf en un console.log, quiere decir que tu PDF desde php ya esta correcto. El siguiente paso es desde javascript decirle como pintar ese binario. El código que esta adentro de  `}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {` es la forma de decirle al navegador como pintar ese binario. Eso es lo que te falta: colocar ese código.

Comment: Ok, no me habia dado cuenta que habias puesto un link del resultado. Posiblemente estas presentando problemas de codificación de caracteres. Prueba hacer esto al final de tu php; `echo utf8_encode($pdf->stream($name_file));` y no uses `return` para devolverlo a javascript, usa `echo`

Comment: Gracias hermano me dio resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate que tu pdf se está generando de forma correcta, creando una ruta GET y accediendo desde el navegador. Luego prueba ésto.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "equipos/generarPdf", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.readyState === 4) {  
        if (oReq.status === 200) {  
            console.log(oReq.responseText)  
        } else {  
            console.log("Error", oReq.statusText);  
        }  
    }
};

oReq.send();
```

**[EDITADO]**

```
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "equipos/generarPdf", true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {  
            if (oReq.status === 200) {  
                var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: "application/pdf"});
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(objectUrl);
            } else {  
                console.log("Error", oReq.statusText);  
            }  
        }
    };

    oReq.send();
```

Comment: el archivo me lo esta creando correctamente, porque primero lo guardo en la carpeta `storage` de laravel e intento descargarlo mediante laravel para que el usuario lo visualice y me retorna, en el `preview`, la imagen expuesta.

Comment: ejecuto tu codigo y laravel me envia un error ***ErrorException
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array*** error que no me hace cuando lo hago con el `ajax` coloquial.

Comment: Ese error parece ser desde php o me equivoco? Cuál es la salida en consola de la petición con XMLHttpRequest? Yo lo probé con $pdf->download

Comment: ya verifique bien y el error era mio, pasa que en el `ajax` que yo hice envio un array por request y en el controlador estaba intentando capturar ese array, por eso me parecia extraño.. ya lo solucione, ahora me crea el archivo como antes pero aun no me lo descarga. Probado tambien con `return $pdf->download();`

Comment: el error que me retorna en consola es el siguiente: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'arraybuffer').
    at XMLHttpRequest.oReq.onload (http://sistematpm.local/equipos:4102:32)`

Comment: @PabloContreras lo siento, también fue mi equivocación, en la edición de mi respuesta verás como es que debería ser, probado y funcionando.

Comment: ¿Como paso el array que utilizo al controlador?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST

en oReq.send() envías los parámetros o formData que desees enviar

Comment: me sigue devolviendo lo mismo:
`%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>
>>`

Comment: estuve leyendo algunas preguntas en SOen y dice que es por que el controlador lo devuelve no esta indicando la cabecera y el navegador no sabe que es y lo toma como un `string`. Indague en el codigo y veo que la funcion download indica la cabecera, [***aca el enlace***](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/src/PDF.php) busca la funcion `download` y veras a lo que me refiero.

Comment: La mejor forma para saber cómo ayudarte, es que crees la ruta Route::get('/generarPdf'), abrirlo en tu navegador, y compartir el resultado de Laravel.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61078/discussion-between-pablo-contreras-and-nex-saloj).

Comment: Me dio solución pero me inhabilitaba distintos plugin y la única manera que encontré para obtener data fue pasando el `id` y consultando de nuevo los datos, la respuesta que dio solución paso los datos al controlador y genero el pdf. Mil gracias por tanta ayuda hermano.

Answer (score 0):

hace poco tuve un problema con ello... y era mi version de php resulta que en mi caso el laragon que reemplaza el xampp estaba con version php 7.0  entonces puedes revisar la documentacion de dompdf y tambien ver que version de php estas manejando y si er mayor pues no vas a poder tendria que cambiar la version de php o crear el proyecto con una version menor de php la que diga en dompdf

Comment: En la info del [**paquete**](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#v0.8.0) leo que dice `php: >=5.5.9` lo que entiendo que se traduce por: **php debe ser mayor o igual a 5.5.9** y en mi proyecto manejo **php 5.6.4**.

Comment: Reviso la versión que dice **xampp** que utiliza y es **PHP Version 5.6.24**.

Comment: si no estoy mal desde ajax no podrías descargar el certificado pdf lo que te recomendaria es que crees una ruta get que reciba los parametros que necesitas.. eso si pues envias un tonkens o algo para no hacer tan evidente la ruta con los valores... entonces ya en la funcion ahi si generas el pdf... con ajax podrias primero verificar que se pueda realizar despues en el succes del ajax redireccionas con js abriendo en una nueva pestaña la ruta get que generara el pdf... en esa ruta pasaras los parametros necesarios.. y al abrirla descargas el pdf inmediatamente

Comment: podrías hacer un ejemplo a ver si te entiendo un poco mas? por favor

Comment: abrí una recompensa para la pregunta