# ¿Como accedo a un archivo creado en la carpeta storage_path() en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pdf

Creo un pdf con el paquete [**barryvdh/laravel-dompdf**](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) de la siguiente manera:

```
public function generarPdf(Request $req) {
    $datos = $req->data;
    Debugbar::info($datos);
    $archivo = storage_path().'\pdf\equipos\\'.$datos[1].'-'.$datos[2].'.pdf';

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('equipos.pdf_vista', $datos);
    $pdf->setPaper('a4');
    $pdf->setWarnings(false);
    $pdf->save($archivo);
    return $pdf->loadFile($archivo);
}
```

Este se crea correctamente, mi problema es al intentar acceder al archivo para mostrarlo al usuario, me aparece que el acceso es denegado, ejemplo:

> Permission denied on C:\virtualhost\Sistema\storage\pdf\equipos\00001-Ulma1.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

Teniendo en cuenta que dicha carpeta no forma parte de la zona "pública" de Laravel, la documentación sugiere hacer un enlace simbólico desde `public/storage` hacia `storage/app/public`.

Existe incluso un comando para generar dicho enlace:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Puedes ver la documentación relacionada: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: ok, ejecuto el comando y me dice que el directorio ya existe (`public/storage`), cambio la referencia de `storage_path()` a `public_path()` y este me sigue diciendo `Permission denied`.

Comment: ¿puedes verificar que el enlace simbólico esté creado?

Comment: No se que es el enlace simbólico :/

Comment: Ummm ok, entonces tal vez debas empezar por ahí, de forma sencilla un enlace simbólico es como una "redirección" local, por favor busca en Google cómo funcionan y cómo se verifican en tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Leyendo algunos temas, lo que entiendo es que al crear un enlace simbólico de carpeta X a carpeta Y lo que se coloque en X se vera reflejado automáticamente en Y. ¿O me equivoco?

Comment: Exactamente, así es.

Comment: Ya corrobore y lo que guardo en `storage\app\public\pdf\equipos` se ve reflejado al instante en `public\storage\pdf\equipos`

Comment: Ahorita estoy creando los archivos en `storage\app\public\pdf\equipos` e intento acceder al archivo desde `public\storage\pdf\equipos` pero me sigue devolviendo `Permission denied`.

Comment: ¿Si conozco la ruta publica lo podría mandar a descargar desde laravel?

Comment: No entiendo tu última pregunta.

Comment: He de suponer q laravel en si ve el archivo pero no permite su apertura por la seguridad, pero ¿Podría laravel leerlo y crear una descarga?

Comment: Acá tengo [**otra pregunta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80749/por-que-mi-app-hecha-en-laravel-no-genera-el-pdf-con-dompdf) intentando generar la descarga:

Answer (score 1):

Una solución a tu problema es que lo soluciones con [*HTTP Responses*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads) de laravel.

Algo que hago yo personalmente, es que me evito el manejo de *enlaces simbólicos*.

Lo que hago es que busco el archivo con **storage_path()** o **public_path()** terminando con la ruta donde debe de estar por ejemplo.

```
$rutaDeArchivo = storage_path() + "ruta_del_archivo_dentro_de_laravel_storage"
```

y termino con

```
return response()->download($rutaDeArchivo);
```

Con esto te debe descargar tu archivo.

Si encuentro el fragmento de código donde hago esto, actualizo esta respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta hermano, pero tampoco me sirve, ya lo había intentado :/

Comment: Pero que es lo que quieres hacer? Descargarla después de guardarla en tu directorio? o descargarla en seguida como sugiere la documentación?